# Python strip date from CSV

Tags: python, date

I've currently got a loop that iterates through each line of a CSV and pulls out information and to enter a website via selenium.

I'm currently struggling with a dropdown box date field. The date is format 30/12/2000.

I think I should be able to strip out each part of the date and send it to send keys in that box and press enter.

I'm using something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime

with open('/Users/me/Downloads/dates_test.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        try:
           driver = find stuff on page
           d = (row[1])
           objd = datetime.strptime(d, '%d %m %Y')
           sign_up_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='membership-signed-up-     on']/a").click()
            sleep(1)
            day1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='membership_signed_up_on_3i']").click()
            day1.send_keys(objDate.day)
            day1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Two questions,

1. I'm currently getting this error.

   ValueError: time data '17/05/2021' does not match format '%d %m %Y'
2. Am I on the right track. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: The formats of your dates are %d/%m/%Y. The format should contain the slashes.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. Just change this line:

```py
objd = datetime.strptime(d, '%d %m %Y')
```

to this

```py
objd = datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I'm getting day1.send_keys(objDate.day)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you do not want to deal with date formats, you could use the `dateutil` library:

```
from dateutil import parser as p

objd = p.parse(d)
```